# how to fix 'gameobject spawn automatically on ground detection'

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on a snooker game that uses vuforia markerless technology.

when i run the application it detects the ground and deploys all the balls(without the table).

when i tap on the screen it deploys the table but without the balls.

The balls have sphere colliders on them and the table has a mesh colliders, both have physical objects selected.

Note: when i run the game,in scene view i can make the balls collide with the surface of the table(moving them on  top of the table and releasing them).

Answer (score 0):

the vuforia engiee works that when  device found the ground,
it will render the mesh with gameobject whatever it has collider,
i use  the fouction resource.load() to load the gb. 
c u discribe u question clearly?or use the photo?